# issue with Animate

Tags: list-manipulation, animation

I want to make a animation based on the dataset like

```
data = Flatten[Table[{x, y, x^2 - y^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}], 1];
```

I show this data using a ListPlot3D.

```
p2[θ_] := RotationTransform[θ, {0, 0, 1}]
```

When I use Table to generate the different images, it works fine.

```
test11 = Table[
  ListPlot3D[p2[a][data] /. {x_, y_, z_} -> {x, y, z*a}, Mesh -> 5, 
   MeshStyle -> White, Axes -> {False, False, True}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}, {-10, 10}}], {a, -1, 1, 0.1}]

Export["anigraf2.GIF", test11, "DisplayDurations" -> 1]
```

When I use 'Animate' to create the same output, Mathematica stops responding en I have to restart the software.

```
Animate[ListPlot3D[p2[a][data] /. {x_, y_, z_} -> {x, y, z*a}, 
  Mesh -> 5, MeshStyle -> White, Axes -> False, 
  PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}, {-10, 10}}], {a, -1, 1, 0.1}, 
 AnimationDirection -> ForwardBackward, AnimationRunning -> True, 
 SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

Is there somebody who has suggestion for this issue?

Comment: For anything but the simplest of graphics objects, **always** avoid `Animate` and use `ListAnimate` instead, since it generates the frames beforehand.  I've had `Animate` crash my entire system before, to where I needed to just restart my computer.  Here, `ListAnimate[test11, AnimationDirection -> ForwardBackward, 
 AnimationRunning -> True, SaveDefinitions -> True]` works perfectly.

Comment: @JasonB, pls make it an answer and elaborate on the issue, so we can succesfully close this Q&A.

Comment: @Louis - done! (comments must be at least 15 characters in length)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anything but the simplest of graphics objects, **always** avoid [`Animate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Animate.html) and use [`ListAnimate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListAnimate.html) instead.

The difference is that `ListAnimate` works on a pre-defined list of images to create an animation.  All the rendering is done beforehand.  With `Animate`, it attempts to do the rendering on the fly, when you are moving the slider.

So this will make the animation you are looking for,

```
data = Flatten[Table[{x, y, x^2 - y^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}], 1];
p2[θ_] := RotationTransform[θ, {0, 0, 1}];
imglist = Table[
   ListPlot3D[p2[a][data] /. {x_, y_, z_} -> {x, y, z*a}, Mesh -> 5, 
    MeshStyle -> White, Axes -> {False, False, True}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}, {-10, 10}}]
   , {a, -1, 1, 0.1}];
ListAnimate[
 imglist,
 AnimationDirection -> ForwardBackward, AnimationRunning -> True, 
 SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

Another option is to use `Manipulate` instead of `Animate`.   `Manipulate` will render the 3D graphics using fewer points when you are moving the slider, giving you the changes quickly when it can at the expense of quality, and then generating the higher quality images when the slider stops moving. (Correct me if I am wrong here) I do not think that `Animate` does this.

So this runs relatively quickly on my machine,

```
Manipulate[
 ListPlot3D[p2[a][data] /. {x_, y_, z_} -> {x, y, z*a}, Mesh -> 5, 
  MeshStyle -> White, Axes -> {False, False, True}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}, {-10, 10}}]
 , {a, -1, 1, 0.05}]
```

[image]

Comment: Well done & cool attitude.