# zooming out and adding text to revolutionplot3D

Tags: graphics3d

I am trying to work some details for to the following animation:

```
Animate[RevolutionPlot3D[Sin[x],{x,0,u},Axes->False,Mesh->5,MeshStyle->Thick,
ViewPoint->Front,RevolutionAxis->{1,0,0},ViewVertical->{-1,0,0},
BoxRatios->1],{u,0,Pi},AnimationRepetitions->1]
```

So I am interested in:

1. completely removing the box
2. zooming out;

as you see here the animation starts with showing the top
half of the spheroid and then it gets squeezed upwards as the rest of the spheroid comes in. I want both the top and the bottom points to be inside the screen at the same time.

3. I want to add text to the top and the bottom point and add other features around the shape, like arrows, etc.

I appreciate any advice that you might have.

Comment: Completely removing the box: `Boxed -> False`. Zooming: look into `PlotRange` and set one manually that includes all the points you want. Adding stuff to a plot: perhaps generate the stuff using graphics primitives in a `Graphics3D` expression, then use `Show` to combine the plot and the graphics within `Animate`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm [always of the opinion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/113623/9490) that you should make a `List` of images that you then feed to `ListAnimate` rather than just giving the image function to `Animate`.  The problem is how `Animate` deals with errors can really hog up your resources, and have it spitting out error messages all over the place.

This is just a proof-of-principle, you will need to adjust it to suit your needs.  What I'm doing here is using a function to spit out the `PlotRange`, this function interpolates between zoomed really close and zoomed out to show the whole plot.

```
plot = RevolutionPlot3D[Sin[x], {x, 0, \[Pi]}, Axes -> False, 
   Mesh -> 5, MeshStyle -> Thick, ViewPoint -> Front, 
   RevolutionAxis -> {1, 0, 0}, ViewVertical -> {-1, 0, 0}, 
   BoxRatios -> 1, PlotPoints -> 80, Boxed -> False];
zoomfunc = 
  Interpolation[{{0, {{0, .1}, {-.1, .1}, {-.1, .1}}}, {1, {{-.1, 
       3.3}, {-1.1, 1.1}, {-1.1, 1.1}}}}, InterpolationOrder -> 1];

imglist = Show[plot
     , Graphics3D[Text[Style["This is the top", 22], {-0.25, 0, 0}]]
     , Graphics3D[Text[Style["This is the bottom", 22], {3.25, 0, 0}]],
     PlotRange -> zoomfunc[#], ImagePadding -> None] & /@ 
   Subdivide[30];
ListAnimate[imglist, AnimationRepetitions -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jason.  I got a couple more questions:

Comment: Firstly, the picture as a whole shrinks in time as we get to the bottom point. I would like to be able to avoid this. Ideally I want to see everything starting from a point at the top and ending at a point at the bottom of the slide. Second, The starting frame seems to be something like x = pi/6, whereas I would like to start from very close to the top point. Lastly, when I export this as .avi, the animation runs twice. Is there a way to have everything run only once? Thanks very much.

Comment: @Sina Just play around with different settings for the plot range, I think that will cover most of the issues.  And I have never had luck with exporting as an avi directly.  I usually export frames and make a movie out of those using another program, or just export an animated gif, and there you can control the number of repetitions